# Web scraper for KCC datasets in data.gov.in

Tags: web-scraping

Suggest me a good online web scraper for downloading all files of KCC farmer queries in data.gov.in website.

Comment: Questions "*seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more*" are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. Consider posting instead to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, but make sure to comply with their [on-topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can install this Python package - [***datagovindia***](https://github.com/addypy/datagovindia/)

```sh
pip install -U datagovindia
```

```py
from datagovindia import DataGovIndia

# Initialize class
datagovin = DataGovIndia(YOUR-API-KEY)

results = datagovin.search(title='KCC',
                        description="Farmer Queries",
                        max_results=1000,
                        print_results=False)
# Returns:
```

```json
[{"5f039cdb2e054ab5b74bfc2a6e1a860b": "Farmers Queries in Kisan Call Centre (KCC) from VIZIANAGARM district of ANDHRA PRADESH for the month of June 2018"},
 {"750fa8d4c3c645688fe5915f5974000b": "Farmers Queries in Kisan Call Centre (KCC) from REWARI district of HARYANA for the month of October 2018"},
 {"1907fc4b1aaf47b4a7241c8e6269c4b4": "Farmers Queries in Kisan Call Centre (KCC) from Shajapur district of Madhya Pradesh for the month of May 2015"},
 {"0c75b02c66ad45fd9237eb3b574423cd": "Farmers Queries in Kisan Call Centre (KCC) from BASTAR district of CHHATTISGARH for the month of January 2018"},
        . . . ,
]
```

```py
# Select an API-Resource ID and download

data = datagovin.get_data("5f039cdb2e054ab5b74bfc2a6e1a860b",num_results="all")

# Returns:
```

|  | season | sector | category | crop | querytype | querytext | kccans | statename | districtname | blockname | createdon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | KHARIF | HORTICULTURE | Fruits | Grape | Nutrient Management | Grape Boron nutrient management | RECOMMENDED TO SPRAY BORAX 2 GR/1 LITRE OF WATER | ANDHRA PRADESH | VIZIANAGARM | PACHIPENTA | 2018-06-19T17:32:11Z |
| 2 | KHARIF | AGRICULTURE | Cereals | Paddy (Dhan) | Weed Management | WEED MANAGEMENT FOR BROAD CASTED PADDY SEEDS IN MAIN FIELD | NOT RECOMMENDED | ANDHRA PRADESH | VIZIANAGARM | KOTHAVALASA | 2018-06-27T08:25:15Z |